# "Slingshot" Style UI Control for React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm looking for a slingshot style aiming control similar to what you'd have in angry birds but perhaps simpler for react native. Another example would be something like this (without the fancy slingshot graphic) https://insights.nimblechapps.com/unity/how-to-implement-slingshot-in-unity

I've tried some implementations with PanResponder/PanGestureHandler and drawing the line in an SVG but it seems quite difficult to position an extended out dotted line this way.

Are there any packages that would help with (or do) this out there? Any tips for a different approach?